# Trying to deploy a project on Github Pages using React/Vite but getting a blank page with an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, vite

I am trying to deploy a React.js/Vite project through [Github](https://github.com/chris-azuaje/portfolio) but I am getting a blank page with the following error: "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec." Here is the [blank page](https://chris-azuaje.github.io/portfolio/).

Does anyone know where the issue lies?

I've tried [this solution](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.js` extension for your JavaScript files instead of `.jsx`.

I haven't deployed to GitHub pages before but from the error you shared, that may be the issue. Let me know if it works✨

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I solved it by changing the branch to the `gh-pages` in Github project settings